# fullPage.js callback browser compatibility issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

I'm using the fullPage.js plugin for jQuery on a website I'm working. on the first page the right navigation is hidden, on the other pages, the navigation is displayed. It works correctly in chrome, however on other browsers it does not display.

A link to the website is : [here](http://www.lambertsyard.com/)

Below is where the callback event occurs. the callback when the user scrolls to that section works correctly, but the navigation does not slide in.

```
var pepe = $.fn.fullpage({
        slidesColor: ['whitesmoke', 'whitesmoke', 'whitesmoke', 'whitesmoke', 'whitesmoke', 'whitesmoke', 'whitesmoke', 'whitesmoke', 'whitesmoke', 'whitesmoke'],
        anchors: ['home', 'about', 'about-more', 'scheme', 'scheme-more', 'history', 'history-more', 'location', 'popup', 'contact' ],
        menu: '#menu',
        afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
            if(index != 1){
                $("#nav-right").show("slide",{direction:"right"},200);
            }
            if(index == 1){
                $("#nav-right").hide("slide",{direction:"right"},200);
            }
        },
        scrollOverflow: true
    });
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In which browsers are you having troubles? I can see the navigation Chrome, Firefox, IE 9... what is exactly the problem with it?

Comment: Have you already solved your problem?

Comment: Yeah, its working now, the problem was that I had the sidebar with height:100%, and I swapped it over to top:0,bottom:0,right:0 and it worked fine then!

Comment: Ok, no problem then :)